# Use HTACCESS to alias subdomain to query

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to alias a subdomain to a search query.

For example, `furry-rabbits.example.com` would alias to `/search.php?query=furry-rabbits`

The address bar must not "redirect" but rather display `furry-rabbits.example.com`

I usually can find an answer to pretty much anything using S.O. but I am an intermediate coder and can't seem to find this answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^(.*)\.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/search.php?query=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: It's important to note that you'll need to add a subdomain wildcard.